# Creating a User Post with the facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to programmatically create user posts to my Facebook feed with the Facebook Graph API, How can I go about it pls. I have seen the procedure to create a post on a Facebook page but not on a user feed. Pls, help!!!

Comment: You can’t, Facebook has removed that possibility a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But is it possible to comment, like, and share a user post?